# Parse Push not working ,pushes sent column comes blank

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push

My parse pushes where working perfectly till yesturday.

But now when I send a push it shows succeded and a green tick but its not recieved and the number of pushes sent column is blank (Not even a zero).
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

possible Causes:

- Check your Api Key and Push Setting for Application in your Parse .
- And Make sure you running it on Same Device.
- Check your Manifest.